# CLRegion or CLCircularRegion cannot be inherited

Tags: ios, objective-c

While I was building an app based on region monitoring, I find CLRegion only have one attribute which is .identifier, I need another `NSString` type attribute to modify the region so I created a class:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface CLCircularRegionObject : CLCircularRegion

@property NSString *soundIdentifier;
@end
```

In the region setting class I create a new class and pass the  region and add extra attribute, the problem is `regionWithSound` is not recognized as a subclass of CLCircluar region.

```
CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:self.annotationView.annotation.coordinate radius:self.radius identifier:self.mySearch.text];

CLCircularRegionObject *regionWithSound;
    if ([regionWithSound isKindOfClass:[CLCircularRegion class]]) {
        regionWithSound = region;
        regionWithSound.SoundIdentifier = self.AlarmSound;
    }
```

Comment: You can't cast a superclass to a subclass. You need to instantiate an instance of the subclass

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paulw~ I change my code to: CLCircularRegionObject *regionWithSound = [[CLCircularRegionObject alloc] initWithCenter:self.annotationView.annotation.coordinate radius:self.radius identifier:self.mySearch.text];
    regionWithSound.SoundIdentifier = self.AlarmSound; Howerever when calling the didEnterRegion method in my delegate class how can I get the  attribute I settled in my custom class

Comment: In `didEnterRegion` you should be able to cast the CLRegion to a CLCircularRegionObject - as long as the framework sends back the same region object you registered. If not then it is probably easier to store your additional information in an NSDictionary keyed on the region identifier.

Comment: originally I was thinking of using the NSDictionary, however, it may need a core data to store the string when user close the app. once start monitoring the device will store the region information into [UIApplication sharedApplication] as a data source. So previously i don't bother with datasource.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't count on the CoreLocation framework preserving your custom subclass across application invocations.

Comment: I tried casting the region to CLCircularRegionObject, it works, however the CLCircularRegionObject is a new created one.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to store your additional data in some other way and correlate it using the region identifier